# Iterate numbers in a df where a condition matches

Tags: python, pandas

Playing around with different data frames whilst trying to teach myself Pandas, this has had me stumped fora while, which seems like a lack in programming comprehension, but could anyone help?

Consider the following df:

```
ID  Name                    Week
1   Matthew                 1751
1   Matthew                 1751
1   Matthew                 1751
2   Jon                     1751
2   Jon                     1751
2   Jon                     1751
2   Jon                     1751
3   Lisa                    1751
3   Lisa                    1751
3   Lisa                    1751
3   Lisa                    1751
3   Lisa                    1751
3   Lisa                    1751
3   Lisa                    1751
```

What I'm trying to do here is add + 1 to the Week number for each occurance in the index but only where the name matches it self.

```
ID  Name            Week
1   Matthew         1751
1   Matthew         1752
1   Matthew         1753
2   Jon             1751
2   Jon             1752
2   Jon             1753
2   Jon             1754
3   Lisa            1751
3   Lisa            1752
3   Lisa            1753
3   Lisa            1754
3   Lisa            1755
3   Lisa            1756
3   Lisa            1757
```

I've tried a simple for loop

but it just increments the length of the index to the number, I've also tried

```
for n in df.Name:
    print(len(n))
```

which just returns the length of each string (rightly) and adding index just returns the length of the index the amount of times n occurs.

am i missing something fundamental? should I create a list first and then pass that to the df?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
df['Week'] = df.Week.add(df.groupby('Name').cumcount())

   ID    Name   Week
0   1   Matthew 1751
1   1   Matthew 1752
2   1   Matthew 1753
3   2   Jon     1751
4   2   Jon     1752
5   2   Jon     1753
6   2   Jon     1754
7   3   Lisa    1751
8   3   Lisa    1752
9   3   Lisa    1753
10  3   Lisa    1754
11  3   Lisa    1755
12  3   Lisa    1756
13  3   Lisa    1757
```

Comment: This is really good, thanks I really envy how quickly you can come up with an aswer. The cumcount is a new one, I'll go visit the pandas docs!

Comment: Very neat answer, +1

Comment: @Datanovice Yw :) happy to help.

Comment: @Vaishali Thank youuu :)

Comment: so sorry forgot to green tick! my apologies Abhi bhai.

Comment: @Datanovice It's fine no big deal.